# flutter gen-l10n versus l10n.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I had the following line in my code:

```
AppLocalizations.of(context).homeScreen
```

As long as I ran `flutter gen-l10n` manually, this line worked as is.

I have now created a `l10n.yaml` file, so that I don't need to run the command manually each time. It contains just 2 lines:

```
arb-dir: lib/l10n
template-arb-file: app_en.arb
```

and now the localization is done automatically with `flutter run`. However, Android Studio reports the line and forces me to add an exclamation mark (or `.?`).

```
AppLocalizations.of(context)!.homeScreen
                            ^ note this
```

The reason is that different code is generated.

Code generated using `l10n.yaml` (line 68 of `app_localizations.dart` on my machine):

```
  static AppLocalizations? of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of<AppLocalizations>(context, AppLocalizations);
  }
                         ^ note the question mark
```

Code generated by using the command line (also line 68 of `app_localizations.dart` on my machine):

```
  static AppLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of<AppLocalizations>(context, AppLocalizations)!;
  }
                         ^ no question mark            exclamation mark ^
```

Why does using `l10n.yaml` make this difference? Is there a way to fix it, so I don't need to add exclamation marks everywhere in my code?

I tried figuring out what command line `flutter run` uses by looking at the output of `flutter run --verbose` but there's nothing inside.

Comment: It that matters: Flutter 2.2.3 stable, Android Studio 31.0.0, no flutter doctor issues.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the following line to your l10n.yaml file:

```
nullable-getter: false
```

See [relevant PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/79263) in the Flutter GitHub project.

Answer (score 2):

`!` is part of the sound null-safety. `!` indicates that the value is not null.

[Learn more about null safety here](https://dart.dev/null-safety)

For Localization,

```dart
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

export 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

extension AppLocalizationsX on BuildContext {
  AppLocalizations get l10n => AppLocalizations.of(this)!;
}
```

Use the above code to us localization as an extension on `BuildContext` like,

```dart
context.l10n.homeScreen
```

l10n.yaml file

```yaml
arb-dir: lib/l10n
template-arb-file: app_en.arb
output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart
```

Comment: I know what `!` does, but I don't understand the difference if I run `flutter gen-l10n` manually or it runs automatically during `flutter run`.

Comment: My issue is that flutter generates different code, depending on how it is run.